# C++ Platform independence layer

Tags: c++, c++11

I am trying to create code that works on several operating systems. I am still new to the entire C++ ordeal so I'm just trying out things.

I was thinking, all the operating systems use different types for the same thing, so I could maybe define my own types that I use across all of my code, and make use of `#ifdef` to leverage these:

I have a header called typedefs:

```
#ifndef TDTYPEDEFS_H
#define TDTYPEDEFS_H

#ifdef _WIN32

#include <windows.h>

#endif

//include for apple and linux

struct Monitor {
    //fields I will use here
#ifdef _WIN32
    static Monitor constructFromNativeType(HMONITOR *hmonitor) {
        return nullptr;
    }

#endif
#ifdef __APPLE__
    static Monitor constructFromNativeType() {
        return nullptr;
    }
#endif
#ifdef __linux__
    static Monitor constructFromNativeType() {
        return nullptr;
    }
#endif
};

#endif //TDTYPEDEFS_H
```

Here I thought; I could create a static method for each platform that converts the platform-specific type to my type that would be used throughout the rest of the code.

Now my questions are,

1. is this a good approach?
2. Are there better alternatives?
3. Will this actually work the way I think it will?
4. Is it better to define all my types in seperate header files per platform and then use `#ifdef` to load the header for that platform?

Furthermore, I would like to set up a CI server (TeamCity, because I use CLion) with an agent for each platform to continuously build my application.

Comment: Hello and welcome to code review! We review working, correct code that you have written or maintain. Your code seems to be about hypothetical code that is not yet written and as such is of topic for this site. You can try SWE@SX for your question.

Comment: Hi! I don't think it's as hypothetical as it is a proof of concept. It is written code, and I'd like someone to review it before I go further with it! This is why I thought this was the place. However, it technically does not compile! :) Thanks eitherway!

Comment: It is stub code which is also of topic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't have much experience in such diverse platforms (my usual idea of cross-platform is "HP/UX, AIX *and* Solaris"), but I'll offer a suggestion anyway.

Your header should contain the *platform-independent* **interface** only:

```
struct Monitor {
    static Monitor constructFromNativeType();
}
```

The different implementations then include the header and provide their own implementations as a library:

```
// This is linux/monitor.cpp:
Monitor Monitor::constructFromNativeType()
{
     return nullptr;
}
```

```
// This is windows/monitor.cpp:
Monitor Monitor::constructFromNativeType()
{
     return nullptr;
}
```

What you have above is certainly not an abstraction layer, as it presents different interfaces according to platform, so the client code needs to have conditionals.

The method name here is rather odd - why does the calling code ever see a platform-native representation?  It should interact with this class only through the abstraction.  As a simple example, consider the `FILE` abstraction in C.  The structure itself is platform-dependent, but portable code can obtain a `FILE*` using `open()`, and doesn't need platform-dependent means to do this.

Comment: Hello, the constructFromNativeType receives the native representation of a monitor, and for each platform, that native presentation is converted into my own type (Monitor) that is then further used throughout my code, not having to worry about anything native. It certainly sounds like a good idea.

Can you explain why a pointer to the same type is suddenly platform independent (because you seem to put focus on that)? Or rather, do you mean the `open()` method that does not require any platform dependent calling? Note that these construct methods would not be called outside of my abstraction.